# Serving static images on django application?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

I am have been having troubles figuring out how to serve static images with my django application. However, I have figured out a sort of "hack" to get it working but it doesn't allow for much flexibility.

In the **html files** I have tried the following...

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}textchange/nextarrow.png" class="foobar" id="foobar">
```

**Above:** The pages will load when I use this but the images will not work.

`<img src="{% static "textchange/nextarrow.png" %}" class="foobar" id="foobar`">

**Above:** The pages will not load, I get a server error

```
<img src="thefullurltoS3bucket/nextarrow.png" class="foobar" id="foobar">
```

**Above:** The images will load fine

I have been trying all these different formats when going to production with Heroku and S3. The question I have is is the way I'm serving my static images correct? I use the last example in which I make the src the full url to the bucket at s3. Is that fine?

It should be noted that when I use the static tag serving css files works fine. Images is the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your first and second solutions ( that you got server error and not loading ) is the correct way of using static files which is:

```
<img src="{% static "textchange/nextarrow.png" %}" class="foobar" id="foobar">
```

review your `settings.py` file and set `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_DIRS` and also `STATIC_ROOT`, if you got server error maybe you set the `STATIC_URL` or `STATIC_DIRS` wrong. you can find plenty of posts about these settings.

Also check your image url in browser ( sth like `127.0.0.1:8000/static/files/etc.jpg` )see if you can access the image.

Answer (score 0):

Serving static files in Django can be a pain.

First, make sure you use the static template tag correctly in your template:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}

<img src="{% static 'path/to/image.jpg' %}">
```

In your settings, have your `STATIC_URL` point to something like '/static/', your `STATIC_ROOT` point to the directory where you'll actually serve your files post-collectstatic, and your `STATIC_DIRS` to where you'll place your static files within your project (i.e. 'static' directory).

If you're serving from S3, you'll probably [follow a tutorial like this one](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/).